# Getting the time zone as a UTC offset on windows and linux

Tags: datetime

What is the simplest way to get the machine's time zone as a positive or negative UTC offset, preferably using some time of shell command?

Answer (score 5):

For all Unix-ish operating systems, when using the GNU date command:

`date +%z`

Example, for Eastern European Time (my timezone):

```
[moocha@helium ~]$ date +%z
+0200
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the non-summer/daylight-savings offset, you'd have to do something like:

```
date -d 'Jan 1' +%z
```

(or Jul in the southern hemisphere).  This works with date from GNU coreutils, anyway.

Shockingly enough, I don't see any way to get the tm_isdst flag from date.

Answer (score 0):

I figure that if worse comes to worse I can just send a request to an NTP server and take the difference of it and the current local time, but that seems kind of wasteful if the system knows its offset.